# Is there a term for a situation when questions in an anonymous survey may alienate the answers of the survey?

Tags: methodology, survey

A friend was complaining to me the other day about a anonymous survey that they started to answer online which made them feel as if the survey was making negative presumptions about them which led to their not completing the survey.  I was wondering if there was a specific term for this sort of situation, where the nature of the survey may alienate or drive away answers of it, and if there was any standard procedures the creator of a survey was expected to do to minimize this outcome?

To protect their privacy I won't go into the nature of the specific survey my friend was upset about, but to give an example of what I'm talking about let's make up an example of a survey that is directed at individuals that view pornographic stories with themes that may be considered non traditional or even anti social like rape, sadism, incest, etc.  This theoretical survey starts with questions that ask things like if the answer was abused as a child, if they came from a broken home, and other generally considered 'negative' childhood experiences, follows by a list of questions about what methods the participant may use to distract themselves from their interest in the material, followed by asking if the answer is a registered sex offender and what issues they had with the law, and finishes with a bunch of questions about how likely they are to engage in the activity in real life and what laws/legal practices are most likely to prevent them from doing so.

The implication of questions in this theoretical survey is that these individuals are a danger to society who can barely control their urges and likely to break the law by acting out the behaviors they are reading about if they haven't done so already.  Meanwhile one of the participants of the survey may argue that just because they read pornography with this content doesn't mean they have any intent on acting on it, any more then watching a violent action movie is going to cause them to go out on a murder spree.  The individual answering  this survey may thus become angered by the content of the survey which they feel is making unfair presumptions or judging them and thus either fail to complete the survey or modify their answers based off of feelings that the survey is 'judging' them, for instance claiming to view the material less often or to get less enjoyment out of the material then they really do because they are left feeling guilty for consuming the material.

Is there a specific term for this potential problem?  Lets say that the nature of the information your trying to collect means that all the listed questions above made sense to ask a participant, are there techniques or approaches that it's recommended one use to minimize the likelihood of upsetting or alienating the individual taking the survey when asking these questions?

Comment: There is a general guideline when creating surveys to ask non-leading questions (unless you have specific reasons to do so). Simply framing a question in one way or another impacts how people answer it. This seems to be a specific case where asking leading questions might be perceived by participants as being judged.